# How to read csv file into Python 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, pandas

For example, I have a csv file like :

```
| a | b | c |
  1   2   3
  4   5   6 
  7   8   9
  10  11  12
```

I need to create a numpy.ndarray from this csv file. For this example, it's size should be (2,3).

and should be like this

```
5(1+4), 7(2+5), 9(3+6)
17, 19, 21
```

Sum the rows in its own(every 2 rows)

Panda, numpy or similary libraries can be used. Actually I am reading the csv with panda but after that i cannot do it.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I don't understand the pattern between the input csv file and the "and should be like this" format? Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see the correspondence.

Comment: For example, I read the csv file. I have to sum every 2 rows inside it own. Is it more clear now. And also i edit my question maybe now it is more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `pandas`, you could use `groupby`:

```
>>> df
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
>>> df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).sum()
    a   b   c
0   5   7   9
1  17  19  21
```

This works because `groupby` can group on something you pass it, not just a column name, and in this case we pass an array with the right group numbers:

```
>>> np.arange(len(df))
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> np.arange(len(df))//2
array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

If you really need an ndarray and not a dataframe, you can access that via `.values`.

```
>>> df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).sum().values
array([[ 5,  7,  9],
       [17, 19, 21]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: actually i will use it on scikit linear regression and OLS so i will check if dataframe is work or not but anyway thanks